# How to install Mapserver on Ubuntu?

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu

I try to install MapServer on Ubuntu by follow this [tutorial](http://mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#installation). I was installed libraries and apach. But have a problem with last command:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c /home/user/mapserver /usr/local/bin/mapserv
```

I have libtool library in system. But its says that directory `/home/user/mapserver` not exist. When i try:

```
    libtool install /usr/bin/install -c /home/user/mapserver /usr/local/bin/mapserv
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory '/home/user/mapserver'
```

Whats wrong?
PS: first time see Linux OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are a first time user, you should definitely install mapserver using provided packages rather than compiling from source.

`sudo apt-get install mapserver` is what you need. If you want a more recent version of mapserver, you should consider adding the [ubuntugis](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) repository first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver
```

Comment: Its fine i do `sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver` and get MapServer.